# What is this "Not logged in" screen from "_ah/login" that appears with oauth2client?

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth

I'm playing with the `oauth2client.appengine` `Oauth2Decorator` and it interjects it's own screen asking for an email address:

[image: Not logged in]

The URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8080/_ah/login?continue=http%3A//127.0.0.1%3A8080/mypage`

I'm guessing that its intention is to mock being different users during development?  But that leaves some questions:

1. Does it only appear on the dev server?
2. Do I have to do anything to make it go away when deploying to production, or is that magic?
3. How do I turn it off for development?
4. What does it actually do?
5. if the user is being redirected to an oauth consent page nonetheless what's the point of this?

As you can see I just don't get it.  I do see that it gives my `get_current_user()` a result - a user instance with the email address that I submit.

I recognise that this is effectively the same question as
"[How to Bypass Local Login Screen with Oauth2 and GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079914/how-to-bypass-local-login-screen-with-oauth2-and-gae)", which seems to conclude that the whole `oauth2client` library is fairly useless and it is best that we all go off and write own authentication flows?  Seriously?

If that's the state of things alternative suggestions are welcome (in the comments).  My workflow is to send the user off to be granted permissions via Google's Oauth so my webapp can proceed to do stuff on their behalf.

Comment: I've just discovered there is also a `get_current_user` in the `google.appengine.oauth` lib.  It produces (in dev) the same structure, but different values as the one in `google.appengine.users`.

Comment: When you deploy you have a very different experience. If the user is logged in it will only prompt for the OAuth. If not it it logs them in first. The OAuth does exactly what you mention in the final paragraph. So while yes its a little annoying to have to click an extra button while in Dev it should not be a reason to not use it in production. Having worked on (and still working on) a few OAuth based Apps the decorator simplifies the process so much more than any issue it causes. +For OAuth to even work the user needs to be logged in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the [`get_current_user()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/functions) that is provided by Google you can't really avoid it and it is actually something very useful. If you want to do your own authentication stuff then just don't use it and you won't be redirected to `/_ah/login`.

In short this is just to simulate locally the actual Google Login. It would be a huge mess to login to your actual account while on development mode and it will be really hard to simulate multiple users. That code is not executed online and instead you are being redirected to Google for approval.

Comment: No. On this `[User Authentication in Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/)` page they tell us to override the page explicitly.

Comment: @JohnMee This link is broken. What did it say? How do you override it?

Comment: @Praxiteles it's outdated now.  Says to try [oauthlib](http://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2/oauth2.html) or [google-auth](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)